# Force evaluation of constexpr static member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I have a problem when I want to check certain template-parameters for their validity using some helper struct and constepxr functions. As long as there is no reference to the static constexpr member I want to initialize the compiler decides not to evaluate the expression. The code I use is the following:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

#define CONSTEXPR static constexpr
using namespace std;

template<size_t ... Sizes>
struct _size_check_impl
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Sizes) != 0, "Dimension has to be at least 1");
    CONSTEXPR size_t dimension = sizeof...(Sizes);
};

template<size_t ... Sizes>
constexpr size_t check_sizes()
{
    return _size_check_impl<Sizes...>::dimension;
}

template<size_t ... Sizes>
struct Test
{
    static constexpr size_t Final = check_sizes<Sizes...>();
};

int main()
{
    Test<> a; // This shouldn't get through the static assert
    Test<1, 2> b; // Passing
    Test<2> c; // Passing
    // cout << Test<>::Final; // With this it works just fine, bc Final is accessed
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way I can do this, some proxy dependecy that forces the compiler to evaluate the `Final` value if constexpr are evaluated? Is there another, clean way to check this property clean and quickly?

Comment: The reason is that the static assertion is dependent on the `Sizes...` parameter, which isn't instantiated until phase two of two phase lookup.

Comment: If `Test<...>::Final` is used anywhere, then its value will be evaluated. If not, it won't. Then you shouldn't care whether it is evaluated or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer would probably be to simply add another `static_assert`:

```
template<size_t ... Sizes>
struct Test
{
    static constexpr size_t Final = check_sizes<Sizes...>();
    static_assert(Final > 0, "");
};
```

This will lead to two separate static assertion failures, though. If that is a problem for you, you could make sure `check_sizes`, or `Final`, is used some other way that must necessarily be evaluated at template class instantiation time, without instantiation of any member, for instance:

```
template<size_t ... Sizes>
struct Test
{
    static constexpr decltype(check_sizes<Sizes...>(), size_t()) Final = check_sizes<Sizes...>();
};
```

Yet another option: if `Test<...>` is a class that is expected to be constructed normally, you could make sure `Final` is used from the constructor somehow.

Comment: I have gone with the first method and removed the static assert from `check_sizes` where it just checks that `Final == 0` to avoid the two assertion fails. I also rushed so fast that I forgot about option 3, although I like the first two options more because they detect the error earlier.